# DNN 7.0 : Can i migrate the .jsp pages in an web application into DNN?

Tags: jsp, dotnetnuke

I want to migrate the pages of an web application containing .jsp pages into DNN 7.0. How can i do it?i tried searching in the Google but all the search results shows migrates from .net to .netnuke. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If the JSP pages are just Content, you can manually pull all that content over into DotNetNuke pages with HTML modules on them.

If the JSP pages are functionality, forms, etc, than you likely will need to convert them into .NET based modules using either C# or VB.Net.

The last option, and probably the easiest to start with, but not a long term solution, is to embed those JSP pages into a DNN site using the IFrame module.

Comment: Thanks Chris..Can i know for migrating The community edition is enough or we have to go for Professional edition?

Comment: It really depends on what features you need. If you're looking for more customizeable permissions, workflow, and sharepoint connectivity than the Professional and Enterprise editions would be good. Otherwise you can likely do everything you need with the free community edition.